# recreate pivot table based on an existing one using vba

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, pivot-table

I know I can record a macro in excel to get the vba code when manually creating a pivot table.

But if I **already** have a **manually** created pivot table in an excel sheet - is there a way to now get the vba code to recreate an equally looking pivot table in another excel workbook (based on the same kind of but other data)?

Comment: Copy the pivot table and change the data source.

Comment: @TimWilliams - yes that is a way, but I believe it wouldn't give me the vba code to repeatedly and programmatically create the pivot table in multiple excel workbooks. I'm trying to find the vba code to recreate the pivot table previously created by other people.

Comment: There's no straightforward way to convert a pivottable into the VBA required to create that pivot table.